# Compiled QT app from source, app doesn’t want to open, even from old commits that were working

Tags: qt

I have this project hosted here:

https://github.com/thistleknot/DiffMatchPatch

I was VERY meticulous and verified each of my commit’s ran a successful compiled version.

However, now… no matter what commit I use, by copying to a new directory, or try to create a new blank project and import old header’s, forms, and cpp files in… I can not get the app to run.  It builds, just never opens.

I even tried debugging my main function by inserting breakpoints and it just skips right by them.

Any ideas? This happened to me last night when someone was assisting me. The compiled app just exits from task manager with no errors or messages. It does ask if I want to run as admin however. But that’s it.

Comment: Please don't commit the `.user` file. It includes your local settings and is useless for others. It could be considered to be outright hostile, in fact.

Answer (score 0):

You're building on a platform that doesn't inform you of things that are wrong. Namely, there are two `main` symbols in the project. You can't have the test harness and the application under test in one project. Those need to be separate projects.

Simply remove `diff_match_patch_test.[cpp|h]` from the project and you'll be all set.